Is LVM broken or xfs filesystem dead?
As we say all too often, never prod on a Friday ... But an admin on my team wanted to expand a lv, so he broke the whole system.
I've managed to remount the disk and the group volume, and now I'm trying to mount the lvs.
But nothing works, and I've tried everything I know in terms of pvs commands, pvscan, vgscan etc ...
Here's the state of play:
[root@xprod1 ~]# pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sdb1  vg_data   lvm2 a--u 362,87g    0
  /dev/sdc1  vg_db1    lvm2 a--u 390,62g    0
  /dev/sdd1  vg_system lvm2 a--u 102,54g    0
[root@xprod1 ~]# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vg_data     1   7   0 wz--n- 362,87g    0
  vg_db1      1   1   0 wz--n- 390,62g    0
  vg_system   1   6   0 wz--n- 102,54g    0
[root@xprod1 ~]# lvs
  LV                   VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_mysqlbin          vg_data   -wi-ao---- 104,18g
  lv_sauvtest          vg_data   -wi-ao----   3,00g
  lv_var_sauvegarde    vg_data   -wi-ao---- 134,59g
  lv_varlog            vg_data   -wi-ao----   1,95g
  lv_varlogcron_applis vg_data   -wi-ao----   1,95g
  lv_www_datas         vg_data   -wi-ao----  97,66g
  lv_wwwhtml           vg_data   -wi-ao----  19,54g
  lv_mysql             vg_db1    -wi-ao---- 390,62g
  lv_home              vg_system -wi-ao----   4,88g
  lv_root              vg_system -wi-ao----   4,88g
  lv_swap              vg_system -wi-ao----  43,95g
  lv_tmp               vg_system -wi-ao----  39,06g
  lv_usr               vg_system -wi-ao----   4,88g
  lv_var               vg_system -wi-ao----   4,88g


mount:
[root@mrf-ame7-n ~]# mount
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_home on /home type xfs (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_tmp on /tmp type xfs (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_usr on /usr type xfs (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_var on /var type xfs (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg_db1-lv_mysql on /var/lib/mysql type xfs (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)

==> lv on vg_data a not there.
[root@xprod1]# mount -t xfs /dev/vg_data/lv_varlogcron_applis /var/log/cron_applis
mount: /dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_varlogcron_applis est déjà monté ou /var/log/cron_applis est occupé
[root@xprod1]# ls -la /var/log/cron_applis
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    6  2 juin  10:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096  2 juin  18:37 ..

I'm unable to mount any lv in vg_data.
For your information, when the operation was performed, my colleague could no longer see the vg or lv on /dev/sdb1.
I managed to restore them by giving the pv its uuid thanks to vgcfgrestore.
/dev/sdc1: UUID="rcmFhy-xELi-aAS5-uu1t-bDIu-uynD-fZIL5V" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/sda1: UUID="e76455b2-3e0f-41b1-9eab-0f7844f1ad52" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdd1: UUID="ZCsmhv-r7fV-4STS-v7L4-i4a5-kM0v-wjCgij" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_root: UUID="2923af9a-72af-40d9-9fcc-e25b4edec58f" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_home: UUID="2feb2a8c-fa29-49c3-9d44-f680a23de34d" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_tmp: UUID="022de6e7-1951-4ec7-98ff-1293bcf461f6" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_usr: UUID="cc02f27a-928f-46f7-8876-a31633dc55e7" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_var: UUID="dd518af2-e149-45cd-9ce3-def93b939bd6" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_swap: UUID="f6051375-07a6-41f4-9a54-31c5dc2634c5" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/vg_db1-lv_mysql: UUID="bd2d90cf-8375-49d4-b464-cd8d2fcdaad4" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="Boho6M-KQKP-3hvi-pTJS-2sXg-aYfq-055NMd" TYPE="LVM2_member"

=> no vg_data-lvXXXX ...
I'm going in circles and I don't know what to do.
